# Ejecución de proceso hijo UNIX/C con execl()

Tags: c, unix

¡Hola! Estoy trabajando con procesos en Unix y me encuentro con el siguiente problema: tengo dos procesos, un proceso padre (**dad**) y un número indeterminado de procesos hijos (**son**). 
Más allá de la funcionalidad del programa, no entiendo por qué se produce un error en la ejecución del proceso hijo al usar *execl()* en el proceso padre. Ilustro...

```
/****************************************************** 
                   dad <n> <t_max>
genera n hijos que esperan un maximo de t_max segundos
para devolver un caracter aleatorio 
******************************************************/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define NOMBRE_HIJO "son"
#define PATH_HIJO "/home/usuario/procesos/son"

/* Variables globales */
int n_procesos, t_max;
pid_t *procesos;

/* Funciones */
void parse_argv(int argc, char **argv);
void init_procesos();
void generar_procesos();
void esperar_procesos();
void liberar_recursos();

/* Logica del programa */
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  parse_argv(argc, argv);
  init_procesos();
  generar_procesos();
  esperar_procesos();
  liberar_recursos();

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

/* parse_argv : tratamiento de la linea de ordenes */
void parse_argv(int argc, char **argv) {

  if(argc != 3) {
    fprintf(stderr, "[DAD] Error en el numero de argumentos. USO dad <n> <t_max>\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  n_procesos = atoi(argv[1]);
  t_max = atoi(argv[2]);

  printf("\n[DAD] Se crearan: %d procesos\n[DAD] Tiempo de espera maximo: %d segundos\n\n", n_procesos, t_max);
}

/* init_procesos : inicializar la tabla de procesos */
void init_procesos() {
  int i;

  procesos = malloc(n_procesos * sizeof(pid_t));

  for(i = 0; i < n_procesos; i++)
    procesos[i] = 0;
}

/* generar_procesos : creacion de los procesos hijo */
void generar_procesos() {
  int i;

  for(i = 0; i < n_procesos; i++)
    switch(procesos[i] = fork()) {
      case -1:
        fprintf(stderr, "[DAD] Error en la creacion de proceso hijo\n");
        liberar_recursos();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      case 0:
        printf("[DAD] Se va a ejecutar el proceso %d\n", getpid());
        if(execl(PATH_HIJO, NOMBRE_HIJO, t_max, NULL) == -1) {
          fprintf(stderr, "[DAD] Error en la ejecucion de proceso hijo %d\n", getpid());
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

  sleep(1); 
}

/* esperar_procesos : espera a finzalizacion de procesos hijo */
void esperar_procesos() {
  int i, j;
  pid_t pid;

  for(i = 0; i < n_procesos; i++) {
    pid = wait(NULL);

    printf("[DAD] El proceso hijo %d ha finalizado\n", pid);
    for(j = 0; j < n_procesos; j++) 
      if(procesos[j] == pid) {
        procesos[j] = 0;
        break;
      }
  }
}

/* liberar_recursos : liberar espacio consumido por estructuras */
void liberar_recursos() {
  free(procesos);
}
```

La **salida** proporcionada es, como ya he dicho:

```
[DAD] Error en la ejecucion de proceso hijo ...
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? ¿Es problema de los argumentos que introduzco en la función **execl()**?

Un saludo y gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Todos los parámetros que se le pasan a `execl()` deben de ser cadenas, salvo el último que debe ser `NULL`. En tu caso le pasas `t_max` que es un entero. Ya que el compilador esperaba un `char *` está interpretando ese entero como una dirección de memoria donde estaría la cadena que espera, y ya que la hipotética dirección a la que apunta no es correcta, probablemente se está produciendo el error `EFAULT`.

Para ver qué error concreto se produce, te recomiendo usar `perror("mensaje")` en lugar de `fprintf(stderr, "mensaje")`.

En todo caso la solución pasa por convertir `t_max` a string (o directamente no convertirlo a entero cuando lo copias de `argv[2]`).

Comment: efectivamente, ¡gracias! Había obviado que los argumentos en execl() han de introducirse como cadenas de caracteres :D